# Why does MVC double-encode unobtrusive validation attributes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

For example:

```
data-val-equalto="&amp;#39;MyProperty5&amp;#39; and &amp;#39;MyProperty4&amp;#39; do not match."
```

**Question:** Why is the & character encoded again into `&amp;` (`&amp;#39;`), instead of just outputting the character reference as is (`&#39;`) ?

The jquery.validate plugin seems to be parsing `&amp;#39;` as `&#39;`.

---

The problem doesn't seem to be in Razor, but with the code that generates the unobtrusive validation attributes, the following code:

```
<span title="@("'MyProperty5' and 'MyProperty4' do not match.")"></span>
```

... outputs correctly:

```
<span title="&#39;MyProperty5&#39; and &#39;MyProperty4&#39; do not match."></span>
```

---

Found out that the problem is in ASP.NET MVC, there's a method called  `GetValidationAttributes` that adds HTML-encoded values to a dictionary, and then the values are encoded again by `TagBuilder`. It would be good to know why they are doing this.

Comment: https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/1198

Comment: I am not able to repro this any more. Do you have a sample repro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed on MVC v4.

Answer (score 3):

Try outputting using the [Html.Raw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) method.

Otherwise, Razor does *not* assume you are trying to output encoded HTML and encodes it again.

Given

```
string text = `Bread &amp; Breakfast`;
```

`@text` will be output as `Bread &amp;amp; Breakfast` because the & is HTML Encoded

`@Html.Raw(text)` will be output as "Bread & Breakfast"

**UPDATE** based on your update

I can't tell you *why* jQuery Validate works that way, but there's an old adage "if it hurts when you do X, stop doing X".

You don't really need to encode the single quote in your output HTML.  Both of the following produce the same result:

```
<span title="&#39;MyProperty5&#39; and &#39;MyProperty4&#39; do not match.">
Span With Encoded Title
</span>
<br />
<span title="'MyProperty5' and 'MyProperty4' do not match.">
Span With non-Encoded Title
</span>
```

Comment: see, my updated question, the problem doesn't seem to be in Razor itself.

Comment: I found out that the issue is in MVC. I'm not producing the content, MVC is, and it's double-encoded HTML.